# When having a css file with over 1000 lines, blazor no longer automatically shows changes. Is there a way to increase this limit?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-7.0, hot-reload

For a while now I wanted Blazor to automatically reload my file. This never worked on my core application, but did work on new projects I started. I just found out why. The reason being that my core application has a css file which has over 2000 lines of css-code.

I experimented with deleting a lot of lines, which resulted in that it started to work at around 1000 lines of css-code. So it seems that there is a limit built in where the reload no longer works.

Question: I was wondering if there is a way to override this limit?

I know the obvious answer to also fix this is to split the file, but I was just wondering if there is a way to override the limit or have it work in general with such big files.

Comment: Very weird and interesting bug (I presume it's a bug), just for my information, do you talk about CSS Isolation file, or a raw CSS file linked in the index.html file?

Comment: [A thought] Have you tried minimizing your Css file?  There are no longer any "lines"!

Comment: @DylanElBar Yeah it seems like a bug or a limitation that was set by the developers, not sure about it. I am talking about the css file linked in the index.html file

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have not yet tried this, since I'm constantly editing the file. A minimized file isn't something I can work with on the fly afaik. Unless there is a way to make changes in the normal/big file, which then generates a minified file on save that I can reference in the index.html that still shows changes on the fly at run time?